# Is Xamarin.Social open source?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.social

Xamarin.Social is [available as a component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.social/), but I can't find its source and [the license](http://components.xamarin.com/license/xamarin.social) disallows decompiling it. I was hoping to fork it to use with my project.

Is there no publicly available source code for Xamarin.Social? If there is, can I fork it?

(I created [a Xamarin Forums thread for this question.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4393/any-plans-to-open-source-xamarin-social#latest))

Comment: it doesn't appear so - the license is here: http://components.xamarin.com/license/xamarin.social

Comment: No - I think it's the same as Xamarin.Mobile - but they have promised to open .mobile up, so maybe .social will follow... maybe...

Comment: @Jason That's what I've seen, but I was hoping that maybe it's just boilerplate template for Xamarin Component license, and the guys don't mind re-licensing it as Apache or MIT/X11 separately.

Comment: possibly, but I would ask directly - support@xamarin.com or their forums.  I think there is an e-mail specifically for the component store, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Jason Updated the question with a Forums link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Xamarin.Social is now on Github.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social)

Comment: Thank you for open sourcing it!